# How to search a word using regex and concatenate it to other words also found by using regex on a per line basis?

Tags: regex, search, replace, notepad++

**I have a file in format:**

*has | have | had\tmeaning of have\n

apple\tmeaning of apple\n

write | wrote\tmeaning of write\n*

**I want to have it in the following format:**

*has\tmeaning of have\n

have\tmeaning of have\n

had\tmeaning of have\n

apple\tmeaning of apple\n*

etc. Word(s) (has, have, had) can be single or multiple. Multiple words are seperated by  space, pipe character, space. Meaning is followed by tab character and ended by new line. I am not sure but want to assume that meaning may contain pipe or tab character (or better any character except newline). Can it be done in notepad++? If not, is there other easy alternative?

My input file uses actual newline and tab characters. Since I can't paste them in stackoverflow, I have presented them as \n and \t (escape sequences) instead in the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

It sounds like in your input, the tabs and new lines are not literally inserted. This should work:

**Search:** `\s*([^ |]+) \|\s*(?=.*?\t(.*?)(?=(?:\R|$)))`

**Replace:** `\1\t\2\n`

**Original**

In the Replace tab, make sure to check the "regex" box at the bottom left, then use this:

Search: `\s*([^ |]+) \|\s*(?=.*?\\t(.*?)(?=(?:\\n|$)))`

Replace: `\1\t\2\n`

[image: NPP regex]

Comment: Hmm.. nothing happens :(

Comment: Just tried it in N++, it works. Sometimes though, depending on your locale, the replacement in N++ uses `$1` syntax instead of `\1`, so try this for the replacement: `$1\t$2\n`

Comment: Strange. I got nothing. I am using version 6.5.3 unicode btw. http://share.pho.to/6JOJS

Comment: Added screenshot. Could a small thing must be missing in the boxes you are ticking ?

Comment: tried checking wrap around, using dollar sign instead of slash. Still nothing. Why does your file contain \t and \n literally? Mine has tab character and newline. Actual characters, not ecsape sequence. I have attached a screen shot too. I can't find any differences.

Comment: `Why does your file contain \t and \n literally?` I pasted what you have at the top of your question. That's probably the problem. If you paste the exact input, I'll look at it again.

Comment: I can't paste tab character and newline character in stackoverflow. They get lost. Even with input above, I don't seem to be able to replicate your results.

Comment: If I understand, there is no literal `\t` written in the text. I have edited the answer: please try the answer at the top for that situation. :)

Comment: that seems to work. why does "meaning of apple" changes to "meaning ofapple" (no space between "of" and "apple"?). Wil this ignore everything in meaning except newline?

Comment: I don't have this `ofapple` problem. Sorry, I've done my best, making all kinds of assumptions about the input, but can't help any further. Wishing you a fun weekend.

Comment: Your last assumption was the correct one. But you can see "ofapple" problem in your screenshot too and I have it with last answer as well. But yeah, you have done your best and I can't complain. Good weekend to you as well.